# How can I detect an ACK flag in an empty packet without using raw sockets?

Tags: php, sockets

I have a server that I have to repeatedly poll to get data from. When the server is finished it simply responds to the last inquiry with an empty packet. Unfortunately the packet isn't available using regular (not raw) sockets in php.

Comment: If PHP does not provide you with raw sockets, I cannot imagine how you would detect this condition. Why PHP specifically? Other languages have libpcap bindings which can make listening to raw packets far easier.

Comment: Php does have raw sockets. I'm just trying to avoid re-inventing tcp just for this purpose. I just happen to be using php for this project. What other languages have libpcap bindings that might come in handy?

Comment: I guess all the popular languages...

Answer (score 1):

As an empty packet doesn't contain any stream data it is not visible for the users of the TCP API.

You *need* raw sockets.

Note: the TCP protocol itself also uses empty packets, for special purposes, eg: for doing TCP keepalive probes. So that server you have has a quite crazy design :/